# ball not moving in my code turtle as intended

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

```
Ball.sety(Ball.ycor()+Ball_y)
Ball.setx(Ball.xcor()+Ball_x)
#BorderLine
if Ball.ycor() > 280:
    Ball.sety(280)
    Ball_y *= -1
if Ball.ycor() > -280:
    Ball.sety(-280)
    Ball_y *= -1
if Ball.xcor() > 380:
    Ball.goto(0,0)
    Ball_x *= -1
if Ball.xcor() > -380:
    Ball.goto(0,0)
    Ball_x *= -1
```

basically im working on a pong game using turtle i tried to make it so if ball went to the upper or lower border it bounces but if ball went to the right or left borders it goes back to 0,0 but now the ball does not move whatsoever

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code here doesn't run on its own--there are undefined variables.

Comment: i can just make a new post and add the whole code in it

Comment: It'd be better to [edit] this post rather than asking a whole new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is here:

```
if Ball.ycor() > 280:
    ...
if Ball.ycor() > -280:
    ...
if Ball.xcor() > 380:
    ...
if Ball.xcor() > -380:
    ...
```

Which probably wants to be:

```
if Ball.ycor() > 280:
    ...
if Ball.ycor() < -280:
    ...
if Ball.xcor() > 380:
    ...
if Ball.xcor() < -380:
    ...
```